# Plugin (extension) for google chrome for analyzing web pages

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

**Dear all,**

I have the next task: I need to create plugin for google chrome which will analyze each visited page in the next way:
1) It will calculate the count of tables, and count of links in current page,
2) and save the result from first step to the file.
so, after each session of opening google chrome we must have file with lines:

"https://www.some_site_address/" "count of tables" "count of links"
"https://www.next_site_address/" "count of tables" "count of links"
...

Maybe someone can help? I am a beginner in this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: please help.. how to start wiht chrome extensions

Comment: I'm not sure if you're interested in this question anymore, but next time use the [tag:google-chrome-extension] tag.